# grive-tools : Depends: libcurl4-openssl-dev but it is not going to be installed

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, dependencies

recently I tried to install Grive Tools, following the instructions from this website [Ubuntu Google Drive Client with Grive and Grive Tools](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/ubuntu-google-drive-client-grive-and-grive-tools). Everything worked perfect until I reached the point where I applied the command `sudo apt-get install grive-tools`. The following error appeared:

```
grive-tools : Depends: libcurl4-openssl-dev but it is not going to be installed
```

I searched online a lot and I found many people saying that `apt-get -f install` will solve the problem, for example [Can't install grive tools in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581427/cant-install-grive-tools-in-ubuntu-14-04).

I tried all suggested solutions and most of the time I end up having this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgnutls-dev : Depends: libgnutls-openssl27 (= 2.12.23-12ubuntu2.1) but 3.2.16-1u1~ppa2 is installed.
 libcurl4-openssl-dev : Depends: libcurl3 (= 7.35.0-1ubuntu2.3) but 7.37.1-1u3~ppa1 is installed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*answer given by Thanos in his question*

The only solution to my problem was found here [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa).

I applied the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

then,

```
sudo aptitude install grive-tools
```

As a final step I had to downgrade some packages to met the dependencies. Sample of process is provided under:

```
sudo aptitude install grive-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils-dev{a} comerr-dev{a} expect{a} grive-tools krb5-multidev{a} libboost-filesystem-dev{a} libboost-filesystem1.54-dev{a} 
  libboost-program-options-dev{a} libboost-program-options1.54-dev{a} libboost-system1.54-dev{a} libboost-test-dev{a} libboost-test1.54-dev{a} 
  libboost-test1.54.0{a} libboost1.54-dev{a} libcurl4-openssl-dev{ab} libexpat1-dev{a} libgcrypt11-dev{a} libgnutls-dev{ab} libgnutlsxx27{a} 
  libgpg-error-dev{a} libgssrpc4{a} libidn11-dev{a} libjson-c-dev{a} libjson0-dev{a} libkadm5clnt-mit9{a} libkadm5srv-mit9{a} libkdb5-7{a} libkrb5-dev{a} 
  libldap2-dev{a} libp11-kit-dev{a} librtmp-dev{a} libssl-dev{a} libssl-doc{a} libtasn1-6-dev{a} libyajl-dev{a} python-pyinotify{a} zlib1g-dev{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 37 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 13.5 MB of archives. After unpacking 141 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgnutls-dev : Depends: libgnutls-openssl27 (= 2.12.23-12ubuntu2.1) but 3.2.16-1u1~ppa2 is installed.
 libcurl4-openssl-dev : Depends: libcurl3 (= 7.35.0-1ubuntu2.3) but 7.37.1-1u3~ppa1 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     grive-tools [Not Installed]                        
2)     libcurl4-openssl-dev [Not Installed]               
3)     libgnutls-dev [Not Installed]                      
4)     librtmp-dev [Not Installed]                        



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Install the following packages:                                                                              
1)     libcurl4-openssl-dev [7.35.0-1ubuntu2 (trusty)]                                                            
2)     libgnutls-dev [2.12.23-12ubuntu2 (trusty)]                                                                 
3)     libgnutlsxx27 [2.12.23-12ubuntu2 (trusty)]                                                                 

     Downgrade the following packages:                                                                            
4)     libcurl3 [7.37.1-1u3~ppa1 (now) -> 7.35.0-1ubuntu2 (trusty)]                                               
5)     libgnutls-openssl27 [3.2.16-1u1~ppa2 (now) -> 2.12.23-12ubuntu2 (trusty)]                                  
6)     libgnutls26 [2.12.23-12ubuntu2.1 (now, trusty-security, trusty-updates) -> 2.12.23-12ubuntu2 (trusty)]     
7)     libgnutls26:i386 [2.12.23-12ubuntu2.1 (now, trusty-security, trusty-updates) -> 2.12.23-12ubuntu2 (trusty)]



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  libcurl3 libgnutls-openssl27 libgnutls26 libgnutls26:i386 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils-dev{a} comerr-dev{a} expect{a} grive-tools krb5-multidev{a} libboost-filesystem-dev{a} libboost-filesystem1.54-dev{a} 
  libboost-program-options-dev{a} libboost-program-options1.54-dev{a} libboost-system1.54-dev{a} libboost-test-dev{a} libboost-test1.54-dev{a} 
  libboost-test1.54.0{a} libboost1.54-dev{a} libcurl4-openssl-dev{a} libexpat1-dev{a} libgcrypt11-dev{a} libgnutls-dev{a} libgnutlsxx27{a} 
  libgpg-error-dev{a} libgssrpc4{a} libidn11-dev{a} libjson-c-dev{a} libjson0-dev{a} libkadm5clnt-mit9{a} libkadm5srv-mit9{a} libkdb5-7{a} libkrb5-dev{a} 
  libldap2-dev{a} libp11-kit-dev{a} librtmp-dev{a} libssl-dev{a} libssl-doc{a} libtasn1-6-dev{a} libyajl-dev{a} python-pyinotify{a} zlib1g-dev{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 37 newly installed, 4 downgraded, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 14.4 MB of archives. After unpacking 141 MB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] Y
Get: 1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu/ trusty/main grive-tools all 1.12 [115 kB]
Get: 2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libgnutls26 i386 2.12.23-12ubuntu2 [374 kB]
Get: 3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libgnutls26 amd64 2.12.23-12ubuntu2 [394 kB]
Get: 4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libgnutls-openssl27 amd64 2.12.23-12ubuntu2 [18.3 kB]
```